# Ionic 4: Transparent Header

Tags: css, web-component, css-variables, ionic4

I want to make my header background color transparent. My HTML is as follows:

account.page.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Account</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

account.page.scss

```
ion-header {
    --ion-toolbar-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This makes the bg color white, rather than being transparent. I also tried settings `background: transparent` to each element via Chrome Inspector. But I am only getting `white`.

Any help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue today and found the following solution to get my menu with transparent toobar in Ionic 5.

Set content to `[fulscreen]="true"`. Remove toolbar color with `--background: transparent`. Set the toolbar to the top of page with `position: absolute; top: 0;`.

```
ion-toolbar {
  --background: transparent no-repeat fixed center;
  --color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

remove the shadow in the header with `class=ion-no-border`

[image: Transparent toolbar in IONIC 4]

Answer (score 3):

Add **fullscreen** to `<ion-content>`

```
<ion-content fullscreen>

</ion-content>
```

Add **no-border** to `<ion-header>`

```
<ion-header no-border>

</ion-header>
```

Comment: this does not fix the issue - the Ionic documentation states that 'fullscreen' must be added to the content, and that 'translucent' must be added to the toolbar. This however, does not work.

Comment: I just set ion-toolbar background to transparent scss file and its fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea. Target the *ion-toolbar* instead of the ion-header in your scss.

**account.page.scss**

```
ion-toolbar {
  --background: transparent;
  --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
}
```

And as mentioned earlier you would add `no-border` to the *ion-header* element and `fullscreen` to the *ion-content*.

**account.page.html**

header

```
<ion-header no-border>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Account</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

content

```
<ion-content fullscreen>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22291719)

Answer (score 2):

Only add this class to `<ion-toolbar>`. You can set color for ion-content and ion-toolbar.

```
ion-toolbar.transparent {
  --background     : transparent;
  --ion-color-base : transparent!important;
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to remove ionic toolbar shadow on IOS and Android**

```
/* Remove bottom border on ios */
    .header-ios ion-toolbar:last-child {
      --border-width: 0;
    }
    
    //remove bottom shadow android
    .header-md::after {
      display: none;
    }
```